# Fixing grid width on windows phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I was wondering if you guide me , how can i fix the grid width or griditem width on windows phone . actually i am beginner in xaml and windows phone. this my xaml code :

```
       <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">

        <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCountry" SelectionChanged="ListBoxCountry_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Grid Background="#FFD0D2D3" Height="180">

                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="Assets/images/icon_bubble_white.png" Stretch="None" Margin="-107,0,0,0" />
                        <Image  Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Icon}"  Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="Fill"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" TextAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
                    </Grid>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

And the ugly view of listbox and you can see grid items has no suitable width size .  :

[image]

Comment: Have you tried removing the Width="Auto" on ColumnDefinition?  Auto means it only takes up the space it needs, rather than spanning the parent control.

Comment: What do you want it to look like? Adding `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to your `ListBox` should fix the part of it, but is that -107 left margin intentional on that image?

Comment: @ErikElkins thank you for replying , yes i used but no change .

Comment: @ChrisW. Now i used HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"   and also i remove that margin . but no change .  i wanna see every row be stretch . as you see the view has a row width problem ,

Comment: Really? With that directly on the ListBox itself (not the itemtemplate) it didn't do it? Huh, didn't expect that. Will have to take another look I suppose.

Comment: @ChrisW. Yes , this is really weird . anyway have you any suggestion to create that template in another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would expect just slapping on the `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` to the `ListBox` would accomplish it fine, but for whatever reason you say that didn't cut it, so we'll just go tell the `ItemContainerStyle` who's boss whether it likes it or not.

Bringing us to something more like;

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">

   <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxCountry" 
            SelectionChanged="ListBoxCountry_SelectionChanged"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
       <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

         <!-- Tell it to do as you wish. 
              Might also use BasedOn if you want to inherit the default stuff with it. -->

         <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         </Style>

       </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>

               <Grid Background="#FFD0D2D3" Height="180">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                   <Image Source="Assets/images/icon_bubble_white.png" />
                   <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" Height="50" Width="50" Stretch="Fill"/>
                   <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              Foreground="White" />

               </Grid>

           </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ListBox>

</Grid>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Cool deal, glad ya got it :)